# Rest Assured: Extracting value from JSON

Tags: java, json, api, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to extract values from JSON with the Restassured usign path.
I want to store it in the String List, because later I will need to check if the  values I have in a csv file exist in this List.

Can anyone help me build a path to extract it?

Now I am getting this on my console.
** (It returned only ten, because I changed the "limit" parameter.)

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

My code until now:

```
// https://svc-uat-cdw/cdw/counterparties.json?2021-05-25?limit=74000&count=false&sort=accountId
    public static List<String> JSONcounterparties(String date ) { 
        baseURI = uri;
        ArrayList<String> accounts =
                    given() 
                        .auth().basic(getJiraUser(), getJiraPass())
                        .param("date", date)
                        .param("limit", "100")
                        .param("count", "false")
                        .param("sort", "accountId")
                    .when()
                        .get("/counterparties.json")
                    .then()
                        .extract().path("accountId");

                
        return accounts;
    }
```

Below you can find the JSON structure, I just need all the "accountId" that are inside the array of objects "identifiers".

```
{
    "organisationId": {
        "#value": "MHI"
    },
    "accountName": "TENARON CAP MGMT AC TCMDBSNY",
    "identifiers": {
        "accountId": "TCMDBSNY",
        "customerId": "TENARNCMSG",
        "blockAccountCode": "TENARNBDBL",
        "identifier": [{
                "accountId": "MHI",
                "accountIdType": "REVNCNTR"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "TCMDBSNY",
                "accountIdType": "ACCOUNTID"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "TENARNCMSG",
                "accountIdType": "MHICUSTID"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "TENARNBDBL",
                "accountIdType": "BLOCKACCOUNT"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "TCMDBSNY",
                "accountIdType": "GLOBEOP"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "NTHFS",
                "accountIdType": "ALERTACRONYM"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "TCMDBSNY",
                "accountIdType": "ALERTACCESS"
            }
        ]
    },
    "isBlocAccount": "N",
    "accountStatus": "COMPLETE",
    "products": {},
    "etc": {},
    "costCentre": "Rate Sales",
    "clientLevel": "SUBAC",
    "accountCreationDate": "2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "accountOpeningDate": "2017-02-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ssi": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this

```
.extract().jsonPath().getList("identifiers.identifier.accountId");
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
.extract().path("accountId");
```

try this

```
.extract().path("identifiers.identifier.accountId");
```

Comment: Thanks @Gunjan, I tried it, but I'm still getting null. But now I am getting one array inside another. ```[[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]] ```